# Angular 5 subscribe not assign data to list

Tags: angular

i am unable to assign data to my qMList. console always showing that list is undefined.
web service is working and data is coming as observable problem is data not assigning to qMList.

```
@Injectable()
export class QuestionService {

  public qMList: QuestionMaster[] ;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

    }

    getOsz():Observable<QuestionMaster[]>{

      return this.http.get<QuestionMaster[]>("http://localhost:7073/api/values");

    }

    getQuestions() {

      this.getOsz().subscribe(res => this.qMList = res);

      console.log(this.qMList);

      }
}
```

Comment: That's because getOsz is asynchronous, so the log statement is printing before `qMList` has been set

Comment: how to avoid this?

Comment: If you move your `console.log` into the subscribe, it'll print fine (`subscribe(res => { this.qMList = res; console.log(this.qMList);})`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is int he fact that http request is asyncronious and you should wait for it to fullfil

```
@Injectable()
export class QuestionService {

  public qMList: QuestionMaster[] ;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

    }

    getOsz():Observable<QuestionMaster[]>{

      return this.http.get<QuestionMaster[]>("http://localhost:7073/api/values");

    }

    getQuestions() {

      this.getOsz().subscribe(res => {
            this.qMList = res;
            console.log(this.qMList);
      });

      }
}
```

Comment: how to do it synchronously?

Comment: there is no way to make request syncronious, why would you need it?

Comment: i want to use for loop for qMList where i put console.log(this.qMList);.

Comment: so make a loop inside of the subscribe section

Comment: in the subscribe section how to return qMList to another component.

Comment: use @Input decorator for another component and provide qMList via html